# What is causing difficulty when I am parsing JSON in react? White screen result

Tags: reactjs, json, parsing, functional-programming

I realise this is likely a very beginner problem but I cant understand what is going wrong here I have simplified the problem to this, I am trying to write a basic app that stores calculators and their values so that I can work on several different calculators at once, here is my basic code in the react .jsx file

```js
function CalcParse(){
    let calculators = require('./Calcs.json')
        .JSON.parse
        .calcs;

    return(
    <div>
        {calculators.map(calc => <p key={calc.name}>{calc.name}</p>)}   
    </div>
        
    )
}
```

and my .JSON file is

```json
{   "calcs":[
    {
        "name":"Extended Surface Rod",
        "args":"h, k, D"
    },
    {
        "name":"Default Calculator",
        "args":"A,B"
    }]
}
```

and then my index.js file is

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import CalcParse from './CalcParse.jsx'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <CalcParse/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

annoyingly my code compiles fine but it comes back with a white screem

Comment: `require('./Calcs.json').JSON.parse.calcs;`? Is that a typo or your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json` file directly by `require`.

```
function CalcParse(){
    let calculators = require('./Calcs.json');

    return(
    <div>
        {calculators.calcs.map(calc => <p key={calc.name}>{calc.name}</p>)}   
    </div>
        
    )
}
```

The better way is:

```
import calculators from './Calcs.json';

// ...

function CalcParse(){
    return (
    <div>
        {calculators.calcs.map(calc => <p key={calc.name}>{calc.name}</p>)}   
    </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: using `import` to import a JSON file is currently (April 2022) not supported in all environments. See [this post](https://2ality.com/2021/06/json-modules.html#why-would-we-want-to-import-json-like-a-module%3F) for more info.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have any issue to use `JSON` in the real product. But your comment is really negotiable. Thanks @Mulan

Comment: If you are using webpack or rollup, you will get this behaviour included. I think the standard will be import assertions.